# React Concurrent Modify Same State

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get errors while modifying a state concurrently.
I have a function called `getAvailableSpace(i, newValue)` which fetch data from the back end and set to the state. This function can be called concurrently. The errors happen when it is called before the last call finished.

```
getAvailableSpace(i, newValue) {
    this.setState(() => {
        let schema_filters = _.cloneDeep(this.state.schema_filters);
        schema_filters[i].loadingSpaces = true;
        return {schema_filters: schema_filters}
    }, () => {
        this.invokeAPI("sitecomparsion", "getallspaces" + this.props.router.location.search + "&selectedTdid=" + newValue.value, requestHeaders.getHeader, (data) => {
            let schema_filters = _.cloneDeep(this.state.schema_filters);
            if(data) {
                //schema_filters[i].availableSpaces = {...data.spaces, ...data.areas}
                let spaces= (Object.keys(data.spaces).map((key) =>{
                    return {label: data.spaces[key], value: ('space_' + Number(key))}
                }))

                schema_filters[i].availableSpaces = [];
                schema_filters[i].availableSpaces.push({label: 'Spaces:', type: 'optgroup'})
                schema_filters[i].availableSpaces = schema_filters[i].availableSpaces.concat(areas)
            }
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                prevState.schema_filters = schema_filters;
                return prevState;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The problem I believe is caused by the race condition since two calls are trying to modify the same state.

Also, I think if the `_.cloneDeep(this.state.schema_filters)` happens before the last call is finished, the update from the last call is lost.
Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of status to update at once, group them all in the same set. State:

```js
this.setState(() => {
   this.setState(() => {
        let schema_filters = _.cloneDeep(this.state.schema_filters);
        schema_filters[i].loadingSpaces = true;
        return {schema_filters: schema_filters}
    this.setState({schema_filters: schema_filters }, () => { 
    // Do something here. 
  });
});
```